# What should be included in an Architecture checklist that aims for technology independence or portability?

Tags: architecture, portability

I'm trying to come up with a set of questions/criteria to assess and evaluate proposed or emergent solutions that make them as portable as possible. What are the most important questions you ask when trying to design, assess or review a set of solutions?

Comment: Depends on the problem I want to solve.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very open and subjective question, so I suspect it will be closed, but in general.

-Separate Concerns
-Build for Deployment
(make sure you can always build & deploy your latest code quickly)
-Build for what is required now, whether portable or not.
-Select tools & technologies that you know to get the job done.
-When large amounts change or scale, re-evaluate the above.